# Android Audio Streaming

Tags: android

Does any one have code they know will run android audio stream from a URL, that will work in android OS 2.2. I have looked on the developer site and there code doesn't seem to work for me. Some of the other code or tutorials are for older versions of android.

This was the code from the code i ve been using(won't work):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Radio extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.radio);
        final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(URL);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
                // This is code for a button that starts the stream when clicked
        Button bRadio = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_stream);
        bRadio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View V) {



                mp.start(); 
    }






        });





   }
}
```

Comment: Please state what doesn't work. Are there any exceptions? Where does URL come from? What URL do you like to stream, what kind of media is there?

Comment: Are you testing this only in the emulator? I've had problems before with audio playback not working in the emulator but working fine in the actual device.

Answer (score 0):

As you are setting `datasource` to *URL*, use **mp.prepareAsync()** instead of **mp.prepare()**.

Answer (score -1):

if you are ok with JNI, there is some sample code [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-audio):

the creating JNI URI player is liking this:

```
// configure audio source  
SLDataLocator_URI loc_uri = {SL_DATALOCATOR_URI, (SLchar *) uri_utf8};  
SLDataFormat_MIME format_mime = {SL_DATAFORMAT_MIME, NULL, SL_CONTAINERTYPE_UNSPECIFIED};  
SLDataSource audioSrc = {&loc_uri, &format_mime};  

// configure audio sink  
SLDataLocator_OutputMix loc_outmix = {SL_DATALOCATOR_OUTPUTMIX, outputMixObject};  
SLDataSink audioSnk = {&loc_outmix, NULL};

// create audio player
const SLInterfaceID ids[3] = {SL_IID_SEEK, SL_IID_MUTESOLO, SL_IID_VOLUME};
const SLboolean req[3] = {SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE, SL_BOOLEAN_TRUE};
(*engineEngine)->CreateAudioPlayer(engineEngine, &uriPlayerObject, &audioSrc,&audioSnk, 3, ids, req);  
(*uriPlayerObject)->Realize(uriPlayerObject, SL_BOOLEAN_FALSE);  
(*uriPlayerObject)->GetInterface(uriPlayerObject, SL_IID_PLAY, &uriPlayerPlay);
```

... get other interfaces...

then you could play:

```
(*uriPlayerPlay)->SetPlayState(uriPlayerPlay,SL_PLAYSTATE_PLAYING);
```